# Default Model Parameters Outperform Optimized Parameters on Test Set - Possible Overfitting?

Tags: classification, optimization, overfitting, hyperparameter

I have performed hyperparameter tuning with cross validation for a classification algorithm on my training data and have tested model performance by making predictions on my holdout set.  I have tested base model performance with default parameters on my test set and compared with the performance of my optimized model only to find that the base model with default parameters performs better than my optimized model.  I'm trying to understand why this would be the case and have considered two likely scenarios for what might be causing this behavior:

1. I have overfit my model parameters to my training data  (my training data was much smaller than the test set as I had performed random undersampling to balance class distribution which was orignally close to a 1:100 imbalance)
2. Random uncertainty due to limited number of test cases (my test data is quite large with over 500,000 rows so I am doubting this is the case)

I'm under the impression that it is more likely that I am overfitting my model to the training data I had used to optimize model parameters.  If this is the case how should I approach parameter tuning in such a way that I do not overfit my model?